# How to load multiple DetailViewController in SplitViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios7

In a split view controller app, how can I push multiple detail view controllers upon selecting a table row in the master view controller?

Just to be clear, I have splitviewcontroller with two different class:
1) `MasterViewController` - left handside View.
2) `DetailViewController` - right handside view

I need to add multiple `ViewController` above the `DetailViewController` using `PushViewController` (as a Stack), when I select a row in the master view controller. How do I wire up the view controllers? From the split view controller? or from the detail view navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace the second view controller with another one, you can should be able to access the `UISplitViewController` via the `parentViewController` property of your master view controller and set a new `viewControllers` array. (See documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // ...

    self.parentViewController.viewControllers = @[self, newViewController];
}
```

Assuming you are in your master view controller containing the table and it has a reference to the currently presented view controller which is a `UINavigationController` you can probably push the desired new view controller on the stack, no matter how often:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  // ...

  [self.detailViewController pushViewController:vc1 animated:YES];
  [self.detailViewController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
  [self.detailViewController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
}
```

This will add three view controllers to the view stack of the `detailViewController`. Adjust the variable names to your situation of course.

Comment: i have detail viewcontroller:

Now on table row selection in master view.......i have to add different Viewcontroller above DetailView.

Comment: Either you overwrite the `detailViewController` property of the Split View Controller or your `detailViewController` is a `UINavigationController` that contains another "detail view". Then you can push another "detail view" onto the Split View Controller "detail stack".

Comment: Done, hope that helps.